# Database Design for storing picture URLs

Tags: sql, database-design, sql-server-2012

I have a table in my database called `Projects`". My `Projects` have more than one picture (building projects)

How to save the source of this pictures in my database?

1. Using a `Picture` column in the `Projects` table?
2. Using other table to save source of pictures?
3. Your idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called [To Blob or Not To Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and analysis is this:

- if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database `VARBINARY` column is more efficient
- if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server 2008's `FILESTREAM` attribute, they're still under transactional control and part of the database)
- in between those two, it's a bit of a toss-up depending on your use

If you decide to put your pictures into a SQL Server table, I would recommend using a separate table for storing those pictures - do not store those pictures in the `Projects` table - keep them in a separate table. That way, the `Projects` table can stay lean and mean and very efficient, assuming you don't always need to select the pictures as part of your queries.